# Magento EE: Missing products in catalog_product_index_price

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm working with a store that runs on Magento EE 1.12. One day we opened up the store and found all the configurable products have gone missing from category listing. I inspected the SQL that loads the products and found out that the inner join with **catalog_product_index_price** had made it return empty.

I opened up the table and found out that while the child simple products of these configurable products are still in the table, the configurable products are not.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Are you running multiple storeviews and what is the status of the products in all storeviews? We ran into a same problem in Magnto 1.12, which equals 1.7 CE I believe. The problem in our case was that on the admin / global level the products were disabled, while they were enabled on a lower storeview level. The disabled status on the admin level caused the price index join to not match the products, resulting in products not showing up on the storefront.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution after tearing down the core indexers. 
I found out that price indexing works by running the stock indexers first then the price indexers. The problem is in one of the configurable product stock indexer.

This indexer renders the **stock_status** of the configurable products stored in **cataloginventory_stock_status_idx** to be 0. The configurable product price indexer then comes in and found out that these products have no stock available so it won't border to reindex.

So the fix is:

In Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock_Configurable
this line

```
$adapter->getCheckSql("{$psCond} AND le.required_options = 0", 'i.stock_status', 0);
```

should be

```
$adapter->getCheckSql("{$psCond}", 'i.stock_status', 0);
```

It's questionable why required_options=0 was there in the first place. Makes little sense to me

Comment: Hello, how do you open this file?

Answer (score 2):

The exact same thing happens when you disable a product and run price indexer afterwards. Magento computes the stock index first, populating the table **cataloginventory_stock_status_idx**. If a product is *disabled* it will be added with **stock_status == 0**. 
From that point on, price index will not be calculated for those products.

Answer (score 1):

The file is under app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock/Configurable.php.  It is named for the class as per [PHP-FIG PSR0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is an old question, I'll leave a possible solution of what appears to be the core issue.

The problem is with configurable attribute's `backend_type` field, it must be always of type `int`, and not `varchar` or whatever.

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97328/47383